# EF Code First unidirectional One-To-Many with Data Annotations

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Say I have the following POCO classes:

```
public class Parent
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
  public int ID { get; set; }

  public int MyParentID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("MyParentID")]
  public Parent MyParent { get; set; }
}
```

The `Child.MyParent` property maps to the `Parent` table with a one-to-many relationship, but I don't want the `Parent` class to be aware of the association (unidirectional).  I can do this within the `DbContext.OnModelCreating` (or any of its equivalents) with the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
  .HasRequired(c => c.MyParent)
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey(c => c.MyParentID);
```

But, I can't seem to find the same with data annotations.  Is there such a thing?  The `ForeignKey` annotation I am using seems to require bidirectionality, because it gives me the "Unable to determine the principal end of an association" exception until I add an `ICollection<Child>` property on the `Parent` class

**UPDATE**
This code should actually work as-is.  The issue I was trying to isolate in my code didn't actually involve this setup.  I've posted a new question regarding my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7761378/437456).

Comment: When do you get exactly this exception? When EF builds the model or when you add/update entities? Does it occur then during `SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

should work. Actually you don't need to do anything - neither in Fluent API nor with annotations - because EF conventions will exactly create the relationship automatically you have defined in Fluent API. The foreign key will be detected because it has the name pattern `[Navigation property]Id`, the relationship will be "required" because the FK is non-nullable and it will be one-to-many because you have a single reference (`Parent`) on one side and "many" on the other side is default if there is no corresponding navigation property.

Comment: Thank you for your response... it made me realize that my framing of the question was too general.  The issue I'm having has to do with the `Child` class referencing `Parent` in a way that breaks convention.  I've updated my question accordingly.  Sorry!

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer: But your updated code still follows the convention. It works without any annotations and Fluent code and also with the FK annotation you've shown in the question (I just tested it). The exception makes no sense for such a model. Is there something else on the `Parent` class, a reference to a single `Child` instead of a collection?

Comment: I've actually discovered the source of my particular issue, and it wasn't related to this.  I've posted a link to my actual problem in a new question as an update to this question.  Thanks for your help!